# Invert colored text related background

Tags: html, css, clip-path, mix-blend-mode

I want to invert text color based on the background of the text, like in  this image: [image].

So I've tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```css
#warp,
#text,
#tri {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#warp {
  background-color: orange;
}

#text {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
}

#text h1 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 150px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

#tri {
  background-color: black;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 99.8% 150px);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 99.8% 150px);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="warp">
  <div id="text">
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="tri"></div>
</div>
```

I found some results about `background-image` & inverted text, but I don't know how to do it with DIVs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid clip-path by using linear-gradient as background and the `mix-blend-mode` will work perfectly:

```css
#text {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#text {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, black 50%, orange 51%);
}

#text h1 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 150px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <h1>TEXT</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Well done. Much more elegant. The only issue here is that you cannot adjust the other color (in this case, light blue)

Comment: @GalAbra no :) you can adjust it by adjusting the mix blend method ;) there is a lot of option that allow to chose what filter to apply

Answer (score 1):

If you just add the same text to the `tri` layer, it works:

**Edit**: In order to allow selecting the text, I've added another transparent layer that wraps all the text as one unit. It does, however, makes updates more repetitive. As a solution, I've added the attached JavaScript code (which isn't necessary).

```js
var text = "TEXT";
var textElements = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
for (var i=0; i<textElements.length; i++) {
  textElements[i].innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
#warp,
#text,
#tri,
#selectable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#warp {
  background-color: orange;
}

#text {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 150px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

#tri {
  background-color: black;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 99.8% 150px);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 99.8% 150px);
  z-index: 2;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

#selectable {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 5;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="warp">
  <div id="text">
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="tri">
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="selectable">
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if the user wants to select the text?

Comment: @Huelfe OP didn't mention that, but you're right. As a part of a better UI, it is preferable. I've added another transparent layer that "wraps" all the text as one unit. However it makes the whole code a bit redundant

Comment: and now the text is repeated 3 times ... no easy to handle

Comment: If JS can be used, it's easy to solve. Anyway, I don't see a way to make this multi-color effect without using multiple layers

Comment: you can have this ;) check my answer ... this is the main purpose of mix-blend that you didn't notice in his code